# How to embed a method result into JSON output when marshalling a type?

Tags: json, struct, go, marshalling

I'm seeking a clean approach to embed the return value of a method into the JSON marshalling of a type/value.
It would be great if I don't need to write custom JSON marshaller.

For example, if the User type has `FirstName` and `LastName` fields and a `FullName()` method, how can I easily embed a `full_name` field into JSON output?

```
 type User struct {
     FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
     LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
 }

 func (u User) FullName() string {
     return fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", u.FirstName, u.LastName)
 }
```

Expected JSON:

```
 {
     "first_name": "John",
     "last_name":  "Smith",
     "full_name":  "John Smith"
 }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This cannot be easily handled without providing *some* marshaller. I understand you don't want to write a `MarshalJSON` and do everything manually, but you can try to extend your structure in the custom marshaller and than rely on the default one. Proof of concept:

```
type User struct {
    FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
    LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
}

func (u *User) FullName() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s %s", u.FirstName, u.LastName)
}

func (u User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    type rawUser User // raw struct, without methods (and marshaller)       
    // Marshal rawUser with an extension
    return json.Marshal(struct {
        rawUser
        FullName string `json:"full_name"`
    }{rawUser(u), u.FullName()})
}
```

[[play](http://play.golang.org/p/L1P95y0ArY)]

You need to cast `User` to `rawUser` to strip all methods – otherwise you would have infinite loop of `MarshalJSON`. Also I've chosen `MarshalJSON` to operate on copy rather than pointer to make sure `json.Marshal(user)` will yield the same result as `json.Marshal(&user)`.

This is not a one liner, but hides the complexity behind a standard interface, so you don't need to remember there's a special, non-standard way of converting your structure to JSON.

Comment: Also, wrt not using the regular marshalling (that is, implementing `json.Marshaler`) rather than a non-standard way; it allows for `User` (or `[]User`, or `map[string]User`, etc) fields to be used in other types and those other types to be marshal-able without any extra effort.

Comment: Great stuff, I especially like the idea to encapsulate JSON marshaling logic inside `MarshalJSON`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a new type and encode that to JSON. If you include an anonymous field of type `*User`, the two get merged:

```
type UserForJSON struct {
    *User
    FullName string `json:"full_name"`
}

func NewUserForJSON(u *User) *UserForJSON {
    return &UserForJSON{u, u.FullName()}
}

func main() {
    u := &User{"John", "Smith"}
    j, _ := json.Marshal(NewUserForJSON(u))
    fmt.Print(string(j))

}
```

[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/840VbN8cva).

It would be nice if we could let User implement `json.Marshaller` instead, and let `User.MarshalJSON()` create a `UserForJSON` object under the hood, but that leads to infinite recursion.

Comment: Thanks, compared to other answers, creating new type for new purpose is more like a standard Go approach.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if  its the "nicest" way to do it but it`s very simple one.

```
func (u User) FullNameMarshal() []byte {
    u.FullName = u.FirstName + " " + u.LastName
    uj, err := json.Marshal(&u)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return uj
}
```

[GO PLAYGROUND](http://play.golang.org/p/N8GF-VmE97)

Comment: If you were to make such a function it should return `([]byte, error)`. You're also modifying the original type definition (you don't show that here but your link); which may be undesirable for many reasons.